# php quotes around variable in array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make a json call with a variable, but keep getting an error since the call isn't registering quotes.

The following syntax makes the notification push send correctly:

```
'include_player_ids' => array('00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000')
```

Where as this method causes it to fail:

```
$playerID = '00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000';
...
'include_player_ids' => array($playerID)
```

The reason being the api requires the quotes around the array item, but I'm not too great at php and can't figure out how to add them around it since this method isn't working for me:

```
'include_player_ids' => array(' . $playerID . '),
```

Good (working) output:

```
"include_player_ids":["00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000"]
```

Bad (non-working) output:

```
"include_player_ids":[00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000]
```

Comment: Can you show us the JSON it _should_ result in, and the JSON the faulty  request results in?

Comment: "include_player_ids":[00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000] is what the server is receiving when the variable is used, whereas it should be displaying "include_player_ids":["00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000"].

Comment: @user3071888 how do you convert array to json string? `json_encode` will not create `[00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000]` without quotes.

Comment: Psst, you can edit that into your question for the rest to easily see as well (I did it for you now). But: that's not something my `json_encode()`  function makes of it, and the bad one is clearly invalid json. Are you using the built-in function or some custom code to build that JSON? Even then: `array($playerID)` should be equal to `array('00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000')` if `$playerId` is equal to `'00000000-6fee-11e4-8ec9-000000000000'`, which leads me to believe there's an error elsewhere... Are you sure you can reproduce the problem with _only_ that difference?

Comment: Thanks for that.  And yes, with only that one change the notification goes from working to giving me an error saying no player ID's were given.  The troubleshooting at GameThrive was unsure how to solve to problem, they could only point out what was going wrong for me on their end(the lack of quotes).  I'm using the php example from the bottom of this page http://documentation.gamethrive.com/v1.0/docs/notifications-create-notification to do the push notificaton.  The only difference being I changed segments to player ids to determine who gets the notificaton.

Comment: @user3071888 you did not answer on the question. How do you convert array with `include_player_ids` into json string? show this part of the code, it creates a problem.

Comment: I found a work around.  I have no idea why, but calling the variables like this:  'include_player_ids' => array($GLOBALS['playerID ']), makes it work now.

Comment: @user3071888 you should post this solution as answer.i solved this problem by writing $GLOBALS['playerID '] from you comment.most of the people just look for answers not comment.and thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sending the POST request as json (with header set to `"Content-Type" => "application/json"`) should work:

```
$fields = (object) [
  'app_id' => $this->appId,
  'include_player_ids' => $playerIds,
  'template_id' => '374e7074-f07d-4743-ad90-5598967e4494', // `daily generic`
];

json_encode($fields);
```